# How to set color to text within <a href>

Tags: html, css

I have the following auto-generated markup:

```
<th id="__ID__TH__" class="__GENERATED_CLASSES__">
    <a href="#" id="__ID__A__" class="__OTHER__GENERATED_CLASSES__">
        Some text
    </a>
</th>
```

I need to apply `color: #21610B;`. The issue is that `th` and `a` tags were generated by an `UI`-framework, so I can't directly affect them. The only thing I can do is apply `style` attribute to both `th` and `a` tags.

Comment: There is something surronding this code? (i.e. a table tag with a specific id)

Comment: @F2K Yes, but that table are generated by UI-framewok.

Comment: Check my answer, just edited :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTML

```html
<th id="__ID__TH__" class="__GENERATED_CLASSES__">
  <a href="#" id="__ID__A__" class="__OTHER__GENERATED_CLASSES__" style="color: #21610B;">
        Some text
    </a>
</th>
```

As the style is inline, it will overwrite any other styling set.

### Javascript

If you are unable to do that, then you can always use a bit of javascript to change the font color.

Pure JS:

```
var x = document.getElementById('someId');
x.style.color = '#21610B';
```

jQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#someId').css('color', '#21610B');
});
```

### CSS

You can also alternatively add it to your CSS. If you know what the class is then set it to the class, if not, you will need to set the !important tag.

```
th a {
    color: #21610b; !important
}
```

or

```
th a.__OTHER__GENERATED_CLASSES__ {
    color: #21610b;
}
```

Comment: but OP says i cant add style  becuase it is generated by UI-framework

Comment: If you can't edit the HTML, the only feasible solution is by adding a specific CSS style as I pointed in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

**[Inline styling is a bad practice.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/138538/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-inline-styling-with-generated-code)**

Can't you insert this style in your CSS file?

```
th a,
th a:link,
th a:hover,
th a:visited,
th a:active, {
    color: #21610b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason the inline styling within the link doesn't work, you could add a `<span>` tag inside the link as well.

```
<th id="__ID__TH__" class="__GENERATED_CLASSES__">
    <a href="#" id="__ID__A__" class="__OTHER__GENERATED_CLASSES__">
        <span style="color: #21610B;">Some text</span>
    </a>
</th>
```

...but it shouldn't be necessary. There isn't much that can override an inline style with the !important tag.

Comment: Why should he add this overhead to every link he wants to style if he can style the `a` element through CSS?

Comment: I stated in the answer that if, for some reason, the inline styling didn't work, this is another option. Even with the other answers he has to add the inline styling to all a elements.

Comment: And to quote the original question " The only thing I can do is apply style attribute to both th and a tags."; meaning he would have to add code each time anyways.

Answer (score 0):

**If you can avoid it remember that using either !important or inline-styles are a terrible practice.**

Please always use CSS specificity in order to override your styles.

Due to CSS specificity inline styles have the highest specificity.

I suggest you to read this article I wrote a while ago:

http://blog4coders.com/css-specificity/

As last resort, if you really cannot override with pure CSS then you can apply those styles in Javascript / Jquery since they will be added as inline styles on top of your CSS stylesheet.

**Javascript**

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".bar");

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.color = "#21610B";
}
```

**JSFIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/a8w2a3hn/1/

**Jquery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.generated-classes').css('color','#21610B', 'important');
});
```

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/a_incarnati/a8w2a3hn/2/

As the css() jQuery method accepts 3 parameters:

```
jQuery.style(name, value, priority);
```

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted, but I don't think it's good to assume he is using jQuery to build a solution. He didn't mention it.

Comment: It's not hard to do it in vanilla javascript, but you see jQuery is one of the most used Javascript library in the world, mostly used for the cross browser automatic support and easy of use. I can edit the answer and add a Js solution if you like. :)

Comment: Ok, edited with both and also added jsfiddle for Javascript and jQuery :)

Answer (score -1):

```
<th id="__ID__TH__" class="__GENERATED_CLASSES__">
    <a href="#" style="color: #21610B !important" id="__ID__A__" class="__OTHER__GENERATED_CLASSES__">
        Some text
    </a>
</th>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add the style attribute:

```
<th style="color: #21610B!important" id="__ID__TH__" class="__GENERATED_CLASSES__">
    <a style="color: #21610B!important" href="#" id="__ID__A__" class="__OTHER__GENERATED_CLASSES__">
        Some text
    </a>
</th>
```